# how to display dictionary data in TableView

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios4

I am using Json to parse the data and currently the data is available in the dictionary and it is also available in the array now i want to show the that data in the table view.
Can some please help.

Comment: you just need to fetch value from key of dictionary and pass it in cellForRowAtindexPath datasouce of tableview..

Comment: did you save the data in nsmutablearray with keys using object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary* dicts = parseJSON;
...
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    return dicts.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"myCell"];    
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell =  [[[ UITableViewCell alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel = [[dicts objectIndex:indexPath.row] objectforkey:@"namefield"];
    return cell;
}
```